# Class 'Swift_Mailer' not found in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, laravel-7, laravel-notification

I am getting this error `Class 'Swift_Mailer' not found` while registering a new user. I have enabled `MustVerifyEmail` on my User model.

I am using mailtrap and Here is my mail configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=54376c8c3sdsds
MAIL_PASSWORD=06a0dbacbsdssd
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@admin.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=LVB
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a fresh installation of Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

First I deleted the vendor/swiftmailer directory manually and ran command,
`composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer`, worked for me.